# How to simply get information on why functions waste CPU time and induce cost?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions

Lately, I got a small invoice from GCP. That surprised me as I always was under all limits, given my project is really small.
Digging into it, I found in the billing information that somehow, a cloud function (firebase functions) used 4200 GHz-seconds on one specific day that is more than 30 days in the past.
Now I'm looking for a way to get more information about that incident, as: Which function? How many times was it called? Did it timeout?

Sadly, the Google Cloud Functions and the Firebase Functions view can only give me information per function for 30 days into the past. So, I have two questions:

1. Is there any way to get more information on what I am technically actually charged for?
2. What is the simplest way to get some kind of early alert (when the 30 day info is still available) when some Google Quotas are exceeded or more specifically, when a function invokes unusual heavy CPU load? Would I need to set up a full monitoring (aka prometheus)?

Comment: Google provides two features. The first is to enable billing export to BigQuery. That provides all billing details that Google records in fine-grain detail. The second is Cloud Logging which will tell you when and how long each function was invoked. Be careful setting up monitoring systems that consume more resources than the resources you are trying to monitor. You can spends hundreds of dollars trying to monitor a dollar of resources.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Posting this as a community wiki to help others that can encounter this issue.

As stated by @John Hanley:

> Google provides two features. The first is to enable billing export to
> BigQuery. That provides all billing details that Google records in
> fine-grain detail. The second is Cloud Logging which will tell you
> when and how long each function was invoked. Be careful setting up
> monitoring systems that consume more resources than the resources you
> are trying to monitor. You can spends hundreds of dollars trying to
> monitor a dollar of resources.